# How do I remove the scroll bar at the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css

The page I created has a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom that scrolls to a large white space. I want the page to be set to the browser's width so it doesn't show the horizontal scroll bar. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

This is what my page looks like. If I scroll to the right, a large white empty space shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcJZv.png

Here is my code.

```html
<html>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&family=Work+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');



        * {
            margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
   
}

    .navbar {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        z-index: 9999;
        
    }

    #page-container {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        
        
    }

    header img {
        width: 20%;
        height: 20%;
    }
    
    li.navigation {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px 5px;
    }
    #outer {
        position: relative;
        

    }
    #inner {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        float: right;
        background-color: burlywood;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        top: 350px;
        left: 50px;
       
        
    }
    p.tiles {
        color: black;
    }
 

    .container {
        
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        padding-top: 20px;
       
        
    }
    .tiles {
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20%;       
        padding: 20px 50px;
        margin: 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
    
    #footer {
        position: static;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 1rem 5rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
       
        height: 24%;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
    }


    .footer-links {
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        
        
    }

    ul.footer-links {
        line-height: 150%;
    }

    .inner-footer-container {
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }

    .form-container {
        margin: 0px auto;
        top: 50%;
        left: 83%;
        bottom: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>

    <head>
        <title>Application of Layout</title>
    </head>


<body>
    <header>
    <div class="navbar">
    
        <ul>
            <li class="navigation">Home</li>
            <li class="navigation">About</li>
            <li class="navigation">Packages</li>
            <li class="navigation">Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    </div>

    <main>
    <div id="page-container">
        <div id="outer">
            <img src="flatlay.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
            <div id="inner">This is an example of a website</div>
        

        <div class="container">
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 5</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 6</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
        


        <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            <div class="inner-footer-container">
            <ul class="footer-links">
                <li><h2>Website.</h2></li><br>
                <li><p>About</p></li>
                <li><p>Press</p></li>
                <li><p>Products</p></li>
                <li><p>Careers</p></li>
                <li><p>Customer Service</p></li>
                <li><p>FAQs</p></li>
        </ul>
        
            <div class="inner-footer-container">
                
                <div class="form-container">
                    <form class="email">
                        <label for="email">Email Us:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="youremail@email.com" required>
                </form>
                </div>
        </div></div>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **form width is `100%` (default block style) but you moved it out with `left: X%`** so your form is out of the container (check in devtools).

Do not use `left` (etc.) for relative elements.

You could rather use something like `display: flex` if you want to make 2 column layout in your footer.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&family=Work+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');


* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;

}

.navbar {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;

}

#page-container {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;


}

header img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}

li.navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

#outer {
    position: relative;


}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
    background-color: burlywood;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 350px;
    left: 50px;


}

p.tiles {
    color: black;
}


.container {

    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;


}

.tiles {
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#footer {
    position: static;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem 5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 24%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

.footer-links {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.footer-links {
    line-height: 150%;
}

.inner-footer-container {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.inner-footer-container {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="navbar">

<ul>
<li class="navigation">Home</li>
<li class="navigation">About</li>
<li class="navigation">Packages</li>
<li class="navigation">Contact Us</li>
</ul>
</header>
</div>

<main>
<div id="page-container">
<div id="outer">
<img src="flatlay.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
<div id="inner">This is an example of a website</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="tiles">
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam
            autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tiles">
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam
            autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tiles">
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam
            autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tiles">
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam
            autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tiles">
        <h2>Heading 5</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam
            autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tiles">
        <h2>Heading 6</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam
            autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
    </div>


    <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            <div class="inner-footer-container">
                <ul class="footer-links">
                    <li><h2>Website.</h2></li>
                    <br>
                    <li><p>About</p></li>
                    <li><p>Press</p></li>
                    <li><p>Products</p></li>
                    <li><p>Careers</p></li>
                    <li><p>Customer Service</p></li>
                    <li><p>FAQs</p></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="inner-footer-container">

                    <div class="form-container">
                        <form class="email">
                            <label for="email">Email Us:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="youremail@email.com"
                                   required>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide horizontal scroll bar applying this style to body element:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to **investigate what is specifically causing the overflow of an element** instead of just hidding it globally with `html|body|* { overflow-x: hidden; }` like people might suggest sometimes. Global aggressive solutions to small and specific issues may fix a problem and create a dozen more.

I just tested deleting arbitrary elements and found that `<div class="form-container">` was causing the overflow. You forced it to be at 83% left regardless of its other attributes and style properties (like width), so it did it.

When you want something to **stick left or right**, you may use `float: right|left;` along with the proper `position` and `display` attributes instead of the `left` or `right` property with a high value. The following changes must fix your problem:

```
<style>

/* ... */

.form-container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    top: 50%;
    /* left: 83%; */
    float: right;
    bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

/* ... */

</style>
```

I changed it and tested it in my browser (using Firefox, last version).

The complete solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&family=Work+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

        * {
            margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
   
}

    .navbar {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        z-index: 9999;
        
    }

    #page-container {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        
        
    }

    header img {
        width: 20%;
        height: 20%;
    }
    
    li.navigation {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px 5px;
    }
    #outer {
        position: relative;
        

    }
    #inner {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        float: right;
        background-color: burlywood;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        top: 350px;
        left: 50px;
       
        
    }
    p.tiles {
        color: black;
    }
 

    .container {
        
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        padding-top: 20px;
       
        
    }
    .tiles {
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20%;       
        padding: 20px 50px;
        margin: 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
    
    #footer {
        position: static;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 1rem 5rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
       
        height: 24%;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
    }


    .footer-links {
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        
        
    }

    ul.footer-links {
        line-height: 150%;
    }

    .inner-footer-container {
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }

    /* Use float instead of left in this case. */
    .form-container {
        margin: 0px auto;
        top: 50%;
        /* left: 83%; */
        float: right;
        bottom: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    </style>

    <head>
        <title>Application of Layout</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>


<body>
    <header>
    <div class="navbar">
    
        <ul>
            <li class="navigation">Home</li>
            <li class="navigation">About</li>
            <li class="navigation">Packages</li>
            <li class="navigation">Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    </div>

    <main>
    <div id="page-container">
        <div id="outer">
            <img src="flatlay.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
            <div id="inner">This is an example of a website</div>
        

        <div class="container">
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 5</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles">
                <h2>Heading 6</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut fuga autem aut Quis nostrum qui adipisci molestiae aut magnam autem aut repudiandae amet?</p>
            </div>
        


        <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            <div class="inner-footer-container">
            <ul class="footer-links">
                <li><h2>Website.</h2></li><br>
                <li><p>About</p></li>
                <li><p>Press</p></li>
                <li><p>Products</p></li>
                <li><p>Careers</p></li>
                <li><p>Customer Service</p></li>
                <li><p>FAQs</p></li>
        </ul>
        
            <div class="inner-footer-container">
                
                <div class="form-container">
                    <form class="email">
                        <label for="email">Email Us:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="youremail@email.com" required>
                </form>
                </div>
        </div></div>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>

</html>
```